# Functional derivative using the Fréchet definition

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, normed-spaces

I've been staring at this problem for far too long and need some assistance. Essentially, I'm trying to prove the following function is differentiable using the [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative):

> Let $X=C([0, 1])$ with the usual max norm. Define $F: X \to X$ as follows for any $f \in C([0, 1])$:
> $$F[f](x) := \int_{0}^{x}f^2(t)\cos(t)dt$$
> Show that F is differentiable at any $f \in C([0, 1])$ and find the derivative.

So far, I've only been able to show:
\begin{align*}
 \left|F(f+h)-F(f)-Th\right| & = \left|\int_{0}^{x} (f+h)^2\cos(t)dt-\int_{0}^{x} f^2\cos(t)dt-Th\right| \\ & = \left|\int_{0}^{x} (2fh+h^2)\cos(t)dt-Th\right|
\end{align*}

where $T$ is the linear transformation for my derivative and $h$ is a function in $C([0, 1])$. To be frank, I have zero idea what I'm doing, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $T(h) \colon [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
T(h)(x) = \int_0^x 2f(t)h(t)\cos(t)dt.
$$
Given $x \in [0,1]$, clearly
\begin{align}
F(f+h&)(x)-F(f)(x)-T(h)(x) \\
&= \int_0^x (f(t)+h(t))^2\cos(t)dt \\
&\qquad \qquad -\int_0^x f(t)^2\cos(t) -\int_0^x 2f(t)h(t)\cos(t)dt \\
&= \int_0^x h(t)^2\cos(t)dt,
\end{align}
and then
\begin{align}
|F(f+h)(&x)-F(f)(x)-T(h)(x)| \\
&\leq \int_0^x h(t)^2|\cos(t)|dt \leq \int_0^x h(t)^2dt \\
&\leq \int_0^x \|h\|^2dt = \|h\|^2x \leq \|h\|^2.
\end{align}
This gives us that
$$
\|F(f+h)-F(f)-T(h)\| \leq \|h\|^2,
$$
so that
$$
\frac{\|F(f+h)-F(f)-T(h)\|}{\|h\|} \leq \|h\|.
$$
Hence, the above quotient goes to $0$ as $h$ goes to $0$ (the zero function).